# JPQL: inner join with group by

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, criteria-api

I'm trying to retrieve data from database using criteriabuilder. It's working great, query is almost perfect... almost. Unfortunately Java don't want me to use group by or distinct as a result of my query. How to make Java retrieve only unique records? My code is here:

```
List<Documentation> documentationList = new ArrayList<>();
DatabaseConnector dc = new DatabaseConnector();
List<Predicate> criteria = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
EntityManager em = dc.getEntityManager();
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();

CriteriaQuery<Documentation> select = builder.createQuery(Documentation.class);
Root<Documentation> u = select.from(Documentation.class);
Join<Documentation, DocumentationUser> du = u.join("documentationUserCollection",     JoinType.INNER);

javax.persistence.Query q = em.createQuery(select);
select.groupBy(u.<String>get("documentationId"));
select.distinct(true);

documentationList = q.setMaxResults(pageSize).setFirstResult(first).getResultList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try swapping 2 lines lower the line that creates the query:

```
select.groupBy(u.<String>get("documentationId"));
select.distinct(true);

javax.persistence.Query q = em.createQuery(select);
```

Comment: Surprisingly it worked! Obvious solution is the hardest one to see ;) Thanks!